# http-outgoing: Shutdown connection

Tags: json, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Performing a JSON POST to a URL results in 'http-outgoing: Shutdown connection' message.

For the life of me can't figure out what's up. The correct id/password are set in the headers. There are no firewall issues. I'm leaning towards it's a DNS setting of some sort. But out of ideas on what it could be..

```
2020-06-27 16:16:33,398 - DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache:77] -  - Auth cache not set in the context
2020-06-27 16:16:33,399 - DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:255] -  Connection request: [route: {s}->https://foobar.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 100; total allocated: 0 of 100]
2020-06-27 16:16:33,399 - DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:288] - Connection leased: [id: 22][route: {s}->https://foobar.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 100]
2020-06-27 16:16:33,400 - DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:235]  - Opening connection {s}->https://foobar.com:443
2020-06-27 16:16:33,402 - DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:139]  - Connecting to foobar.com/10.00.00.001:443
2020-06-27 16:16:33,528 - DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:96] -- http-outgoing-22: Shutdown connection
2020-06-27 16:16:33,528 - DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:129] -- Connection discarded
2020-06-27 16:16:33,528 - DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:326] - Connection released: [id: 22][route: {s}->https:/foobar.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 100; total allocated: 0 of 100]
```

Comment: Please state the version of HttpClient you are using and post a _complete_ wire / context log of the message exchange

Comment: httpclient--4.5.3. The only wire logs received are in the original post. i suspect it's a DNS issue after being up half the night debugging -- there are 2 IP Addresses to the domain being called, and apparently multiple A names associated to the 2 IP addresses. Unfortunately I can't share the actual URL being called due to a vendor NDA :(

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest 4.5.x release and post the complete wire / context log of the session (obfuscate sensitive bits if necessary)

Comment: how to get the complete wire / context log of the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL cipher on target was not supported by the JDK in the source system.

Performing a tcpdump zeroed in on that it could be SSL.

Subsequently, increasing the debug logging on SSL confirmed the issue.

Updating to latest JDK resolved the issue.